Spring JPA Repository not working in CDI managed transaction
I tried to use Spring JPA Repository in CDI transaction context but got "WFTXN0084: UserTransaction access is forbidden in the current context" error. The environment is JBoss EAD 8 / Spring 6.1 / Jakarta EE 10.
I have a JSF backing bean, and a service object (CDI managed bean) is injected into the backing bean
@Named("registrantDetail") 
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrantPageBean {

    @Inject
    private RegistrantService registrantService;

The service object is annotated with @Transactional (jakarta.transaction.Transactional)
@Named("registrantService")
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
public class RegistrantServiceBean implements RegistrantService {

    @Inject 
    @SpringBean
    private RegistrantRepository registrantRepository;

The RegistrantServiceBean has an injected RegistrantRepository. The @SpringBean is a custom qualifier used to wrap around the Spring ApplicationContext to produce Spring bean in CDI context.
So far so good, only when I run the following within the RegistrantServiceBean:
    Registrant = registrantRepository.findById(id);

I'm getting the following error: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFTXN0084: UserTransaction access is forbidden in the current context".
Is there any way I can fix this and make it work?
